# UIButton tint color affected the background color of the button in selected state

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, tintcolor

I have a button with typeSystem that has a specific image on normal state and a different one for a selected state. Problem is, when I set my button to selected state, the image won't show and the button's background is colored with the tint color. 
Is there any way to disable it from happening and showing the image I set for selected state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem` you should replace it with `self.yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];` this will forego the tinted selection option you are getting. Then you can alter it's states images as the following:

```
[self.yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselectedImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Now the tint won't display and your selected/unselected images will retain that image until you alter the state again

Comment: Thanks :) I have used this before, I was just wondering if it will be possible to have the button as type system, and have the same effect? The reason I prefer the typeSystem over custom, is because I can give the button a tint color, while in typeCustom it isn't affected by it.

Comment: @rcat24 the image you have now should still be displaying. You have issues elsewhere. I was just answering the question in your last sentence since it seemed like your desired result. However you can always emulate a tint by just photoshopping your selected image to include whatever background your going after.